# Access the UICollectionViewCell Components in custom method

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have some components in `UICollectionViewCell` and i can access all inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. I need to access the component in a custom method,

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // UIButton
    cell.btn1.frame =CGRectMake(380,100, 150, 40);
    [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  return cell;
}
```

In custom method,

```
-(void)btnClicked{
MycollectionclassView *cell =[[MycollectionclassView alloc]init];
cell.btn1.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Here I cannot change the color of the button.

Comment: When do you need to access the cell? Like when selecting it, or when it is visible or something else.

Comment: @Subash When it is visible, I want to access it.

Comment: I got it right, I thing what you want to do is "On click of a button inside UICollectionViewCell there is a method gets fired and in that method along with other operation you want to change button background". Is this you want to do???

Answer (score 1):

You must create a protocol and create a IBAction to a method. When your action method is called, you can notify the protocol and its screen that has the UICollectionView protocol will receive this event.

**On your cell header file.h define the protocol:**

```
@protocol YourCellNamelDelegate <NSObject>

@required
/**
 *  Notifies that current ITEM was clicked on icon.
 *
 *  @param cell The current cell that was clicked.
 */
-(void)bookmarkClicked:(YourCellName *)cell; // OR without argument


@interface YourCellName : UITableViewCell

/**
 *  Reference to 'YourCellNameDelegate' delegate.
 */
@property (assign,nonatomic) id<YourCellNamelDelegate>delegate;

...
```

**On your cell file.m**

```
...

- (IBAction)bookmarkClickAction:(id)sender {

   // change or update screen element here ...

    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate bookmarkClicked:self];
    }

}
```

**On your ViewController implement the your protocol**

```
@interface SMGListViewController () <YourCellNameDelegate>


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// get your cell here, for example in my case:    

    SMGCityGuideCollectionViewCell *cell;
    cell = (SMGCityGuideCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SMGTouristInfo *touristInfo =  [self.listTouristInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell setTouristInfoCell:touristInfo];

    // IMPORTANT HERE *************************
    cell.delegate = self;  
    // IMPORTANT HERE *************************

    return cell;
}
...


#pragma mark <SMGPlaceCellDelegate>

-(void)bookmarkClicked:(SMGPlaceCell *)cell {

    // notify events here ...

    NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableViewPlaces indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableViewPlaces reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: When we use a protocol in iOS we have to register the delegate to receive events.

Answer (score 0):

To make things clear , when cellForItemAtIndexPath gets called it is the time that your cells get laid in the view , in your custom method you are just creating a cell object but this object does not reference the objects that is laid out in your collection view , so your just changing the color of a newly created object that does not reference anything .

Answer (score 0):

In the Button Click function pass arguments as Sender , by which in the function call you can access the collectionView cell as Sender.SuperView .

You can also find the indexpath from the collectionviewcell now.

Now if you want to update a UI of the Collection view cell , you will have to do it in the cellforItemAtIndexPath function. which can be called by [collectionview reloadData].

So I would suggest to keep some flag variable in the data source to check if you have to update the UI or not.